# need help on ajax suggestion dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I Have an ajax suggestion dropdown and i want to make it display a number of team names but it displays ".$team."

My HTML is

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">



    <style type="text/css">



    #mainContainer{
        width:660px;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:left;
        height:100%;

        border-left:3px double #000;
        border-right:3px double #000;
    }
    #formContent{
        padding:5px;
    }



    /* Big box with list of options */
    #ajax_listOfOptions{
        position:absolute;  /* Never change this one */
        width:175px;    /* Width of box */
        height:250px;   /* Height of box */
        overflow:auto;  /* Scrolling features */
        border:1px solid #317082;   /* Dark green border */
        background-color:#FFF;  /* White background color */
    color: black;
        text-align:left;
        font-size:0.9em;
        z-index:100;
    }
    #ajax_listOfOptions div{    /* General rule for both .optionDiv and .optionDivSelected */
        margin:1px;     
        padding:1px;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:0.9em;
    }
    #ajax_listOfOptions .optionDiv{ /* Div for each item in list */

    }
    #ajax_listOfOptions .optionDivSelected{ /* Selected item in the list */
        background-color:#317082;
        color:#FFF;
    }
    #ajax_listOfOptions_iframe{
        background-color:#F00;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:5;
    }

    form{
        display:inline;
    }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/ajax-dynamic-list.js"></script>
   <center>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
                    <h1>Enter your team team name to see starting 11 and Crest</h1>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="team">Team: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="team" name="team" value=""   onkeyup="ajax_showOptions(this,'getTeamsByLetters',event)">
                    <input type="hidden" id="team_hidden" name="team_ID"><!-- THE ID OF the country     will be inserted into this hidden input --></td>
                </tr>   

            </table>        

        </fieldset> 
        </form>
  </center>


    </body>
    </html>
```

This takes from my php which has the list of teams stored here which the html gets from

```
<?php
$string = 
"arsenal,
manchester united,
manchester city,
 cheslea,
tottehnam hotspur,
 southampton,
 everton,
 aston villa,
 leicester city,
westham united,
newcastle united,
queens park rangers,
sunderland,
swansea,
hull city,
 west bromwich albion,
crystal palace,
 burnley,
stoke city";

$aTeams = explode(',', $string);

if(isset($_GET['getTeamsByLetters']) && isset($_GET['letters'])){
    $letters = $_GET['letters'];
    $letters = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 ]/si","",$letters);
    //$res = mysql_query("select ID,teamName from ajax_countries where TeamName like '".$letters."%'") or die(mysql_error());
  foreach($aTeams as $key => $team) {
    $team = strtolower($team);
    if(strpos($team, $letters)!==false)
      echo $key."###".$team."|";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: How come a "please fix this code" (without even the full code!) question gets two upvotes?

Comment: I ask that all the time @moonwave99

Answer (score 0):

Your php function is not returning anything. Plus, you are echoing every single team, but you are not attaching it to the others. Can you provide the ajax_showOptions function? I can't find it

What happens if you try with:

```
 $res = "";

  foreach($aTeams as $team) {
    $team = strtolower($team);
    if(strpos($team, $letters)!==false)
      $res.= $key."###".$team."|";
  }

return $res;
```

Comment: i get the return ".$team."in the suggestion box on one line and on another line I get ";  }return $res;?>

Answer (score 0):

you need to collect the results to some variable then echo it:

```
    if(isset($_GET['getTeamsByLetters']) && isset($_GET['letters'])){
        $letters = $_GET['letters'];
        $letters = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 ]/si","",$letters);
        //$res = mysql_query("select ID,teamName from ajax_countries where TeamName like '".$letters."%'") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = "";
      foreach($aTeams as $key => $team) {
        $team = strtolower($team);
        if(strpos($team, $letters)!==false)
         $result .= $key."###".$team."|";
      }
print_r($result) // see in your console what value it gives in response.
    }
    echo $result;
```

Comment: i get the return ".$team."in the suggestion box on one line and on another line I get ";  }}echo $result;?>

Comment: there is no return $res .

Comment: Ok, let's try another way. What if you write `foreach($aTeams as $team)` instead of  `foreach($aTeams as $key => $team)` ?

Comment: still the same "; } } echo $result; ?> and ".$team.

Comment: you should better use print_r($result) and check in console.

Comment: @theLibertine no need that is correct,i think he has problem in his view page.

Comment: Sorry @suchit I think i've tried editing you answer instead of mine. Didn't mean to do anything to your code, it was a mistake.